# Hide invitations on work calendar, only show imminent events

Tags: ios, calendar, exchange

I have an Exchange work calendar syncing with my iPhone (iOS 11.3) and often I have many new work invitations appearing on my iPhone notifications and subsequently on my Apple Watch too.
For all of these invitations, I manage the replies (Accept/Decline) on my work computer. The only reason I have my iPhone syncing with my work calendar is to see which events are coming up in the next 15 minutes, and to see which room they're at.

Is there any way to hide all *work* event invitations from my iPhone? I only want to see the events as part of my iOS calendar.
I don't want any work events appearing in my notifications (except event reminders shortly before the event happens; those are fine). Lastly, I'd like to keep my personal event invitations, so turning off all calendar notifications doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage these notifications in Settings > Notifications > Calendar. This will allow you to configure your notification preferences individually for both invitations and upcoming events. There isn't a "turn notifications off" toggle for them individually, but you can manually disable all of the alerts (sounds, badges, banners etc.) for invitations alone.

---

*I misread the last part of your question. My mistake. I don't know if it is possible to adjust notification preferences for individual accounts. I ran into this issue a while back and never found a solution.*

So, in summery this is a no, you can’t have some notifications and not the rest.